# Detect commits within a subfolder, not within the repository

Tags: svn, commit, subdirectory

Our project, for historical reasons, is a large SVN repo with actual separate projects held within separate hierarchical directories.

We want to have separate jobs build these separate sub-projects.

How can we detect commits within a subdirectory of the SVN repo?

Comment: Do you want hook?

Comment: I am aware that I can achieve this with a hook, but this pushes the event instead of allowing a system to pull/poll/search for it. I was looking for a pull solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need `svnlook changed`. Please check the [relevant page of svnbook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svnlook.c.changed.html):

> Print the paths that were changed

I'm using the `svnlook` to create automatic ignore in repository (in my case: if I add a `foo.tex` file (LaTeX) then a hook will add `foo.pdf` to `svn:ignore` on this directory, see [here](http://uzsolt.hu/notes/svn/automatic-ignore.html) (in hungarian but you can check the script)).